# Android - Fused Location: How to get force fresh location

Tags: java, android, location

I've an app which allows usage if user is in certain area, meaning I don't need to track the user, but I need to make sure location that's received is fresh (even if it requires waiting).

What's the best way to do this? Currently using:
 `getLastLocation()`
 but it can sometimes get previous location, understandably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [register a location listener](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates) and proceed to the code if the location condition is met:

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            //if(this is the location) jump to the code which makes the app usable
        }
        //stay unusable
    };
};
```

getting the location might take some time. If by force you mean holding the ui thread until the precise-enough location is available then force getting the location is a bad but feasible idea.